# VBA Select a range of cells within a table dataBodyRange using column names

Tags: excel, vba, range, excel-tables

Lets suppose we have a named table in excel with several columns C1,C2,...,C20. I want to select and process the table rows containing only the C10 .. C16 columns (for example). How to select this part of the table's data body?

Unfortunately, the VBA MS document pages are somehow ... hard to interpret for me. My tips are the followings (none of them work I think):

```
let subTable1 = range("MyTable[C10]:MyTable[C16]").DataBodyRange
let subTable1 = ListObject("MyTable").Range("[C10]:[C16]").DataBodyRange
let subTable1 = ListObject("MyTable").DataBodyRange.Range("[C10]:[C16]")
```

I need another part of the table (last column values):

```
let subTable2 = ListObject("MyTable").DataBodyRange.Range("[C20]") ' ??
```

In this case the two subTables has the same amount of rows. When I want to set the values inside the C10..C16 columns to a new value based on the cell value on the same row at the end (C20 column) the following code should work:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(subTable.Rows)
  let row1 = subTable1.Rows(i) ' expected has 7 columns inside which are C10 .. C16
  let row2 = subTable2.Rows(i) ' expected has 1 columns inside
  computedValue = row2.Cells(1,1).Value * 2
  for each cell in row1.Cells
     cell.Value = computedValue
  next
next
```

So - back to my question: how to select the subTable1 range from a given table? Any solution is appreciate! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work if your columns are next to each other.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim WholeTable As ListObject
    Set WholeTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("MyTable")
    
    Dim SubTable1 As Range
    Set SubTable1 = WholeTable.ListColumns("C10").DataBodyRange.Resize(, 7)
    
    MsgBox "Subset of '" & WholeTable.Name & "' is address " & SubTable1.Address

End Sub
```

Another way of doing it if the columns aren't next to each other:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim WholeTable As ListObject
    Set WholeTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("MyTable")
    
    Dim SubTable1 As Range
    Dim lCol As ListColumn
    'Look at each column.
    For Each lCol In WholeTable.ListColumns
        'Remove the leading C from the column name leaving just the number.
        Select Case Replace(lCol.Name, "C", "")
            Case 10 To 16
                If SubTable1 Is Nothing Then
                    'If it's the first column then set it.
                    Set SubTable1 = lCol.DataBodyRange
                Else
                    'If it's not the first column Union it with the first.
                    Set SubTable1 = Union(SubTable1, lCol.DataBodyRange)
                End If
        End Select
    Next lCol
    
    MsgBox "Subset of '" & WholeTable.Name & "' is address " & SubTable1.Address

End Sub
```

Comment: First use case for Resize(...) which has sense for me :) Thanks. I'll try it!

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()

    Dim colnames, nm, i As Long, z As Long
    colnames = Array("C10", "C11", "C12", "C13", "C14", "C15", "C16")
    
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyTable")
        z = .ListColumns("C20").Index 'end column
        For Each nm In colnames
            i = .ListColumns(nm).Index
            .ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[" & z - i & "]*2"
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Creative solution it is I can say! :) thanks for giving me some ideas!